# can i fit clutch friction plate of same size but different company for old motorbike?

Tags: suzuki, clutch-plate

Hey guys i've been searching for clutch friction plate for my suzuki tc100(1976)model. I couldn't find it so I'm curious if it's possible to fit with other plate of the same size if i could get one and if i dont what else can i possibly do to bring my dads historic bike to life? Im so desperate about this bike so Please

Answer (score 2):

If it's only the friction material that is worn then you can get that replaced.

Also, there are clutch shops that have all the details of diameters (internal external) springs, thicknesses and can source a replacement.